# XNA 3d physics engine

Tags: 3d, xna, physics, collision-detection

I am looking for a 3D physics engine for XNA. I heard of some options, but what I need is:

- free for commercial purposes (preferable open-source)
- support for rigid body dynamics
- support for per-polygon collision (this is very important)
- managed code - has to work on XBOX360

Have you used something like this? Can you recommend something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would look at [JigLibX](http://www.codeplex.com/JigLibX). It's a C# port of the JigLib engine and has support for all the things you need. It also comes with quite a lot of samples, and if you have any experience with physics engines it shouldn't be too hard to work with it.

Also, you might want to take a look at [this thread](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/7574.aspx) over on the Creators Club forums where some XNA physics engines are being discussed.

**EDIT** Also, I forgot to mention that I have used JigLibX myself for a couple of projects and it works like a charm even doing some fairly heavy physics simulations.

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer years after it was made, JigLibX seems to be the most complete 3D physics engine for XNA. However, it has some inefficiencies, some bugs (like a bug with heightfield<->ray intersection in some cases), and lacks support for some basic shapes (like cylinders).

Comment: For anyone searching for a good 3D physics engine for XNA, it is worth trying BEPU physics. https://bepuphysics.codeplex.com/ It is open source, free for non-commercial use, very well documented and afaik it is the most recent and updated one (with latest release from December 2013 when writing this comment).

Answer (score 1):

www.bulletphysics.com includes a C# port, i believe.

Answer (score 0):

APE physics engine, C#, MIT license

[APE](http://aphysicsengine.svn.sourceforge.net/)